# Problem with for-if loop statement operation on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement

I have a dataset which I want to create a new column that is based on a division of two other columns using a for-loop with if-conditions.

This is the dataset, with the empty 'solo_fare' column created beforehand.

The task is to loop through each row and divide 'Fare' by 'relatives' to get the per-passenger fare. However, there are certain if-conditions to follow (passengers in this category should see per-passenger prices of between 3 and 8)

[image]

The code I have tried here doesn't seem to fill in the 'solo_fare' rows at all. It returns an empty column (same as above df).

```
for i in range(0, len(fare_result)):
    p = fare_result.iloc[i]['Fare']/fare_result.iloc[i]['relatives']
    q = fare_result.iloc[i]['Fare']
    r = fare_result.iloc[i]['relatives']
    
    # if relatives == 0, return original Fare amount
    if (r == 0):
        fare_result.iloc[i]['solo_fare'] = q
    # if the divided fare is below 3 or more than 8, return original Fare amount again
    elif (p < 3) or (p > 8):
        fare_result.iloc[i]['solo_fare'] = q
    # else, return the divided fare to get solo_fare
    else:
        fare_result.iloc[i]['solo_fare'] = p
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Did you get the : "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame", error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably not use a loop for this but instead just use `loc`

if you first create the 'solo fare' column and give every row the default value from Fare you can then change the value for the conditions you have set out

```
fare_result['solo_fare'] = fare_result['Fare']

fare_results.loc[(
    (fare_results.Fare / fare_results.relatives) >= 3) & (
    (fare_results.Fare / fare_results.relatives) <= 8), 'solo_fare'] = (
        fare_results.Fare / fare_results.relatives)
```

Comment: This does work. Out of curiousity, was there a reason you can spot why my forloop method did not work?

Comment: the issue is with how you are setting the values to the solo_fare column if you replaces `fare_result.iloc[i]['solo_fare'] = p ` with `fare_result.loc[i, 'solo_fare'] = p ` it should work but using a loop for this process is bad practice and relatively slow

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to initialize those new colums first ?

By that I mean that the statement `fare_result.iloc[i]['solo_fare'] = q`
only means that you are assigning the value q to the field `solo_fare` of the line i

The issue there is that at this moment, the line i does not have any `solo_fare` key. Hence, you are only filling the last value of your table here.

To solve this issue, try declaring the `solo_fare` column before the for loop like:

```
fare_result['solo_fare'] = np.nan
```

Comment: Yes, the `solo_fare` column was already initialized beforehand. The df image in the question is the starting point after initializing. Tried also with `= np.nan` with same issue

Answer (score 0):

One way to do is to define a row-wise function, and apply it to the dataframe:

```
# row-wise function (mockup)
def foo(fare, relative):
    # your logic here. Mine just serves as example
    if relative > 100:
        res = fare/relative
    elif (relative < 10):
        res = fare
    else:
        res = 10
    return res
```

Then apply it to the dataframe (row-wise):

```
fare_result['solo_fare'] = fare_result.apply(lambda row: foo(row['Fare'], row['relatives']) , axis=1)
```